# Multiple branches of one project with bower

Tags: javascript, git, angularjs, angular-ui, bower

I am trying to install two different modules from [angular-utils-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils) with bower. I need only event and jq modules. However it seems like bower can't have code from multiple branches in one folder/repository.

So when I want to install jq after I've already installed the event module I have to choose suitable version for angular-ui-utils and the other is overriden.

```
$ bower install angular-ui-utils\#event-0.1.1
$ bower install angular-ui-utils\#jq-0.1.1

Unable to find a suitable version for angular-ui-utils, please choose one:
    1) angular-ui-utils#event-0.1.1 which resolved to event-0.1.1 and has build as dependants
    2) angular-ui-utils#jq-0.1.1 which resolved to jq-0.1.1
```

I don't need the whole angular-ui-utils file and it seems like a waste to load the whole script. Is it possible to achieve this?

Or should I reconsider using bower? It still seems like the project is not mature enough.

EDIT:

It feels like this syntax would solve the problem, but it's not parsed by bower. In bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-utils": ["event-0.1.1", "jq-0.1.1"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply assign different names to the two versions - Bower will store each one in a separate directory, just like any other 2 dependencies.

In `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-utils-event": "angular-ui-utils#event-0.1.1",
    "angular-ui-utils-jq": "angular-ui-utils#jq-0.1.1"
}
```

then run `bower install` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks man, it works! Is this somewhere in the bower docs or where did you find the info?

Comment: @davekr Essentially I used [dependencies format specification](http://bower.io/#defining-a-package) with a dose of invention :)